# Assign people an award after 7 days, Cron? Commands?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, logic

I'm making a website which awards people with a badge 7 days after they registered.
The application will send them a mail. Now i'm wondering

How can i do this without them having activity on the site? I can make it work that when they login i check the time that has passed since their registration. But i want to do it automatically

### Should i do this with CRON?

Since i'm using laravel i've seen that laravel has **Commands**

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands#building-a-command

Is that also a possibility?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A popular package for this kind of job is [Dispatcher](https://github.com/Indatus/dispatcher) which uses Laravel commands but with the power of a cron job. What I would personally do is create a dispatcher command that runs daily, gets the accounts created 7 days ago and then award the badges in batch.

Answer (score 1):

Make a cron job run everyday and check the users for 7 days and award them a badge accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Cron is probably your best friend for these type of tasks.

If you're just getting started or if your project is of small-scale, cron will fit the job perfectly.

Otherwise, if you're looking into a more scalable solution, a queue and a scheduler would better fit those situations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes cron is the best option for this.
You can setup the cron execution on your server, which will automatically hit the url after the defined time. Cron setup is also available through cpanel.